# What does 薄紅 mean in the following context and how does it relate to the whole sentence?

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics

The following is a line from the song 花紀行 by Yumi Arai. 薄紅 seems to mean rose pink (the color), but can also mean a thin layer of lipstick (of the same color, presumably). I think both the noun and the grammar trips me up here.

薄紅が なんて優しいの
拾い集める人もいないのに

Is this to be grammatically understood as:

薄紅 is gentle/tender because no one collects 薄紅?

If so, I'm lost. I've also then excluded the も particle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the first time I've heard of the song, I'm writing this as a speculation.

## Situation

In song situation, season is past spring.

It's 桜の散る時期 (The season when cherry blossoms falling).

main character of the song are standing (or walking) and viewing はらはら散る桜.

```
Have you seen Cherry Blossoms falling?
```

wind blow off cherry blossoms (薄紅色の桜の花びら).

the character feel kindness for those color.

nobody collect falled (falling?) cherry blossoms. (誰も拾い集めない)

## Consideration

the character feel kindness because 薄紅色 is 「優しい色 (Please Search)」.

> 拾い集める人もいないのに → nobody collect those

but Japanese originally has no custom for collecting those.

So I think the meaning of this part,

「誰も見向きもしない」 (nobody pay attention to those.)

## Conclusion

The character feel tasteful by viewing beautiful color cherry blossoms scattering.